# casperjs submit form without button

Tags: casperjs

I'm trying to get to a download on the other side of this form, but there's no button to click. How can I tell casperJS to execute the function document.forms.item(0).submit()
so I can get to the file?

```
<form action="/Login?ReturnUrl=GetRecepisse&amp;r=++7DsodrsYlc9WAUmEBtwVkiAONQjiyw3tjrpi5kjPlx6dDdwAim9zIzxpYGZpE+gtwXyLoyR5svQKRnulLAdg==" method="post">
    <input id="TempUsername" name="TempUsername" type="hidden" value="" />
            <input id="TempPassword" name="TempPassword" type="hidden" value="" />    


    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        document.forms.item(0).submit();
    </script>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I tried :
`casper.start(casper.cli.raw.get('target'));

 
 //page.evaluate(function() {
 casper.evaluate(function() {
  
  this.echo('Here in evaluation');
  document.forms[0].submit();
  
 });`

But it doesn't seem to do anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally got it working by making a POST request instead...

```
casper.start();

casper.open(casper.cli.raw.get('target'), {
method: 'post',
data:   {
    'TempUsername': '',
    'TempPassword': ''
}
```

});

Then I just used the on('resource.received',... method to capture the returned file...